# INNER JOIN or CROSS APPLY to a User Defined Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

My `UDF` is simple, it does not receive parameters. It does return a result set that I want. So for example:

```
CREATE Function MyTest()
RETURNS @retResultset TABLE
(
    LogDate DATETIME NULL
)
-- return some rows
```

When I was searching the web, everywhere people were saying we need to use `CROSSAPPLY` if I want to join that `UDF` with a normal database table.

But I just tried a normal join and it compiled and didn't give errors.  So now I want to know if there is something I am missing if I join the normal way like this below:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyLogs ml
INNER JOIN MyTest() mt ON ml.UtcTimeStamp = mt.LogDate
```

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag because the question is clearly about that database.

Comment: By the way, if you are joining with a condition then you should probably feed the `ml.UtcTimeStamp` through as a parameter and filter inside the function. And inline Table-Valued Functions are normally much faster than what you have which is a multi-statement TVF

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine . . . because the function takes no arguments.

You need `APPLY` when you want to pass arguments from the first table reference.  This wouldn't work, for instance:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyLogs ml JOIN
     MyTest(ml.UtcTimeStamp) mt
     ON ml.UtcTimeStamp = mt.LogDate
```

If you used `APPLY`, you would need to move the condition to a `WHERE` clause (or use a subquery):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyLogs ml CROSS APPLY
     MyTest() mt
WHERE ml.UtcTimeStamp = mt.LogDate
```

Comment: Great, thank you for explanation of when to use which